# speed-based tracking

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to make speed-based tracking that moves the speed of AX-12 servo motors based on the speed of my joints (my body) using kinect, but I don't know the mechanism how to get the speed by using kinect.. Anybody know ??

Do I must get kinect frame rate first ?

How to get the speed of my joints (my body) using kinect ??

I hope that someone can help me ^_^

Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60465/speed-based-tracking/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Or simpler, if you are using openni.

[EDIT] : the [pi_tracker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pi_tracker) is the one I meant. Openni tracker only gives transforms, not coordinate of the joints.

If you have a look at the tracker file, you'll see that you can access to the points coordinates. Then computing a velocity is the easy part. However, I have no idea how to command your motors (but I hope you know it ;-) )

To access the points, it easy : make a listener, then access the parts you are interested in :

for each joint (here corresponding to index k), you have the following fields

```
msg.position[k].x
msg.position[k].y
msg.position[k].z
msg.orientation[k].x
msg.orientation[k].y
msg.orientation[k].z
msg.orientation[k].w
```

[EDIT 2 ] = the pi_tracker has already something to command velocity for a robot, based on joint velocity....

I hope it'll help you,

Bests,

Steph

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0